# Change Record Integration

Tags: ssis, integration

We have the need to perform an end of day process to extract the daily transactions from System A and transfer only the changes to System B.

The problem is that System A can only provide the full set of transactions available in System A.

My initial thoughts were to use a staging table (SQL Server) which will persist the data from System A, and then is used for comparison purposes for each execution of the end of day comparison. This can all be done using table joins to identify the required UPDATEs, INSERTs, DELETEs.

Not being an SSIS expert I understand this could be done in SSIS using LOOKUPs to identify the additions, updates and deletion.

Question:

1. Is the SSIS solution a better approach and why (maintainability, scalability, extensibility) ?
2. Which would be better performing? Any experience on these 2 options?
3. Is there any alternative option?

Comment: What sort of data volumes are we talking about in the source and destination systems? What version of SQL Server is the destination machine (2005, 2008, 2008R2, 2012)? What edition (standard, enterprise, datacenter, BI edition)?

Comment: Do you care about this question?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the full set of transactions from System A, that limits your options as far as source goes. I recommend pulling that data down to a Raw File Destination. This will help you as you develop, since you can just run the tasks that need that data over and over again without refetching. Also, make sure that the source data is sorted by the origin machine. SSIS is very weak with sorting unless you use a 3rd party component (which may be a career-limiting decision in some cases).

Anyway, let's assume that you have that sorted Raw File lying around. Next thing you do is toss that into a Data Flow as a Raw File Source. Then, have an OLEDB (or whatever) source that represents System B. You could use Raw File for that, also, if you like. Make sure that the data from System B is sorted using the same columns you used to sort System A.

Mark the Sources with IsSorted=True, and set the SortKey value on the appropriate columns in the metadata. This will tell SSIS that the data is pre-sorted, and it will permit you to JOIN on your key columns. Otherwise, you may wait days for SSIS to sort big sets.

Add MultiCasts to both System A and System B's sources, because we want to leverage them twice.

Next, add a Merge Join to join the two Raw File Sources together. Make System A the left input. System B will become the right input when you connect it to the Merge Join. SSIS will automatically set the JOIN up on those sorted columns that you marked in the previous step. Set the Merge Join to use LEFT JOIN. This way, we can find rows in System A that do not exist in System B, and we can compare existing rows to see if they were changed.

Next up, add a Conditional Split. In there, you can define 2 output buffers based on conditions.

> NewRows: ISNULL(MyRightTable.PrimaryKey)
>   UpdatedRows: [Whatever constitutes an updated row]

The default output will take whatever rows do not meet those 2 conditions, and may be safely ignored.

We are not done.

Add another Merge Join.

This time, make an input from System B's MultiCast the left input. Make an input from System A's MultiCast the right input. Again, SSIS will set the join keys up for you. Set the Merge Join to use Left Join.

Add a Conditional Split down this flow, and the only thing you need is this:

> DeletedRows: ISNULL(MyRightTable.PrimaryKey)

The default output will take all of the other rows, which can be ignored.

Now you have 3 buffers.

2 of them come out of your first Merge Join, and represent New Rows and Updated Rows.
1 of them comes out of your second Merge Join, and represents Deleted Rows.

Take action.